# How to determine whether a polynomial has integer roots?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials

A polynomial

$$f(x) = x^n + a_{n-1} x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_1 x + a_0$$

where $a_{n-1}, a_0$ are known. How to determine whether polynomial $f$ has integer roots? Can we give a bound of $\max\{a_i \mid i=1,\dots,n-2\}$ and $\min\{a_i \mid i=1,\dots,n-2\}$ decide by $n,a_{n-1}$, and $a_0$ such that the polynomial roots are integers.

Comment: See the earlier question, "[Polynomials all of whose roots are rational](http://mathoverflow.net/q/97307/6094)." In particular, see the [answer by Daniel m3](http://mathoverflow.net/a/97331/6094) using Hensel's Lifting Lemma, and the comment by Mark Sapir suggesting this leads to a polynomial-time algorithm via LLL.

Comment: Are the $a_i$ integer numbers?

Comment: @PietroMajer If they are not, the answer is negative.

Comment: I imagine the question may be to get bounds on the coefficients here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand just what you're asking, but perhaps it is the following:

> Suppose we know $a_0$ and $a_{n-1}$, and we know that $f(x)$ has only integer roots.  Can we use this information to meaningfully bound the coefficients?

If that's what you're asking, then the answer is no.  Consider for example the polynomial
$$
g(x) = x (x^2 - c^2)^{k},
$$
where $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then this has $a_0 = a_{n-1} = 0$.  But even for fixed $n$, the other coefficients are unbounded if you let $c$ be large.

---

### This part added in response to Timothy Chow's comment:

Timothy Chow made the suggestion that allowing $a_{0} = a_{n-1} = 0$ feels like cheating, and on reflection, I agree!

**If we allow $a_0 = 0$, then we can't get any bound on the other coefficients**

Namely, just consider any monic degree $n-2$ polynomial of the form $p(x) = x^{n-2} + b_{n-4} x^{n-4} + b_{n-5} x^{n-5} + \cdots + b_0$.  Then look at the polynomial $x (x+a) p(x) = x^n + a x^{n-1} + a_{n-2} x^{n-2} + \cdots + a_1 x + 0$.  This will have integer roots, and the coefficient $a_{n-1}$ is free to be any integer you like.  Yet the other coefficients can be wild.  For concreteness, consider this
$$
h(x) = x (x+a)(x^2 - c^2)^k,
$$
which, for fixed $a$ and $k$, will have unbounded coefficients if you pick $c$ large enough [e.g., the sum of these coefficients is $h(1)$ which is unbounded].

**If we disallow $a_0 = 0$, then we do get a bound**

However!  If we disallow the case $a_0 = 0$, then *yes* you can get a bound on the remaining coefficients.  Namely, if $f(x)$ factors as $f(x) = \prod_{i} (x +r_i)$, then we know $a_0 = \prod_{i} r_i$.  If none of the roots is $0$ (i.e., if $a_0 \neq 0$), then each root is at least $1$ in absolute value, and thus $|a_0|$ is an upper bound on every product of the form $\prod_{i \in S} |r_i|$.  Therefore, we have

$$
|a_{n-k}| = \left| \sum_{|S| = k} \prod_{i \in S} r_i \right| \leq  \sum_{|S| = k} \prod_{i \in S} |r_i| \leq \sum_{|S| = k} |a_0| = {n \choose k} |a_0|.
$$
This bound is tight of course by the polynomials $(x+1)^n$ and $(x-1)^n$. (This reminds me of Newton's inequalities, which probably can provide an alternate proof.)

Comment: Somehow allowing $a_0=0$ feels like "cheating" to me. Can you modify your example to avoid that? More generally, is it true that for *every* choice of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_0$ there exist polynomials with only integer roots with unbounded coefficients?

Comment: @TimothyChow, that's a really great question.  Let me add a note to the above addressing that.